# Matlab: Assemble submatrices whose #cols and #rows are stored in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, submatrix

I have two vectors, **R** and **C**, which have the number of rows and columns, respectively, of submatrices that I need to assemble in a ones matrix **I** (40x20). There's 12 submatrices total.

```
R = [4     2     4     4     2     4];
C = [4    16    16     4];
```

Moreover, all the elements of each submatrix have its value stored in vector **k**:

```
k = [3 2 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 ]; % 24 elements
```

Thus for instance, submatrix **M**(1:4,1:4) has 4 rows, and 4 columns and value equal to k(1) = 1.

**QUESTION**: How can I assemble matrix M with all submatrices?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**EDIT**:

The matrix M should look like this:
[image]

and the submatrices:

[image]

and the values of k:

[image]

Comment: R and C are not same size.
Your question is not so clear. Could you provide input and output samples ?

Comment: What's the size of the second matrix containing `k(2)`, 2 x 16? Where does it go in `M`? Can you show a few more of the submatrices to make clear what should be the final structure of `M`? Right now I see no way to combine `R` (length 6) and `C` (length 4) to make up 12 submatrices. Is it 24 submatrices maybe? Also, in which order?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, updated k, and pasted the picture of the matrix from Excel.

Comment: I tried to read your question 3-4 times and I'm just more confused. What are R and C used for ? And how come `submatrix M(1:4,1:4) has 4 rows, and 4 columns and value equal to k(1) = 1.`

I can see that the sub matrix has 4 rows and cols, but what is the purpose of it that you say `k(1)=1`

Comment: I just updated the plot, it was wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that R, C, and k should have the same size?!?

Comment: R and C, indicate the number of columns and rows respectively of the submatrices M11, M12, .... there's 24 submatrices, hence k is 1x24. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
R1 = repelem(1:numel(R), R);
C1 = repelem(1:numel(C), C);
[CC RR] = meshgrid(C1, R1);
idx = sub2ind([numel(R), numel(C)], RR, CC);
result = k(idx);
```

Instead you can use cell array, fill it with sub matrices and then convert the cell array to a matrix.

```
carr = cell(numel(R), numel(C));
k1 = reshape(k,numel(R),numel(C));
for ii = 1:numel(R)
    for jj = 1:numel(C)
        carr(ii,jj)=repmat(K1(ii,jj), R(ii), C(jj));
    end
end
result = cell2mat(carr)
```